# Wrong link in the blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, blog

While reading [How You Can Use the New Stack Overflow Bot from Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/25/can-use-new-stack-overflow-bot-microsoft/?cb=1) blog, I tried clicking the `aka.ms` link, which redirected me instead to Microsoft's [home page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/).

When I looked at the address link in the lower left of the browser, I noticed that the link ends with `-`, compared to the link name which ends in `sample`, so I tried to copy the link, then append the missing `sample`, which now worked.

So, can this be fixed?

I also noticed that it has the same location with the next link, that is linking to its [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/tree/master/StackOverflow-Bot) page, so maybe it is redundant?

For reference:

[image]

Comment: all of this is already discussed under the comment section of the above mentioned blog post

Comment: The discussion is about that the link doesn't work, but no answer